# Subtle Body Or Physical Body Abilities

Tags: shaktism, saint

Shakta Saints Flying, Walking On Water, Living Underwater :

Hey guys, so as I’ve been looking up different Shakta saints, there are many instances where they’re able to fly in the sky like birds, live underwater, walk on water. Is this with the physical body or the subtle body ? I’m assuming this is with the physical body ? Plz excuse if this is a dumb question. Any info greatly appreciated thx :D